# Trapping errors when no query criteria is given in MS Access

Tags: ms-access-2007

I am writing a small database using MS Access 2007. I have in it a function for running queries and printing reports. Printing works just fine if any one of the multiple query criteria is give.

I also want to trap errors and present a message if the user clicks the "Print" button without a query criteria. At the moment I only get a run-time syntax error message which has a "debug" button for accessing the entire code. I want a message that will say "Sorry, there was no search criteria".

This is the code for printing:

```
Private Sub cmdPrint_Click()
Dim varWhere As Variant
    varWhere = BuildFilter

    ' Update the record source
    Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM q_Vehicles " & varWhere

    ' Requery the form
    Me.Requery

    ' Check if there is a filter to return...
    If IsNull(varWhere) Then
        varWhere = ""
    Else
    'The WHERE clause does NOT need the word "WHERE"

        ' strip off "WHERE " in the filter
        varWhere = Mid(varWhere, 7)
    End If

DoCmd.OpenReport "rpt_Vehicles", acPreview, , varWhere
End Sub
```

Comment: [Error Handling in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Just as a fast fix for it. You have two options You can have the report open with no criteria or have it request criteria before opening. Bear in mind I have no idea what BuildFilter returns so the varWhere may never be null in which case the code will need to be modified. Let me know if you have any issues.

To have it only open the report if there is criteria listed:

```
    Private Sub cmdPrint_Click()
    Dim varWhere As Variant
        varWhere = BuildFilter

If isnull(varWhere) Then ' Check if null
  Msgbox "Sorry, there was no search criteria" ' Msgbox opens then stops code
Exit Sub ' Stop the code from running
End if

        ' Update the record source
        Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM q_Vehicles " & varWhere

        ' Requery the form
        Me.Requery

        ' Check if there is a filter to return...
' This was already checked above so is not necessary anymore
'        If IsNull(varWhere) Then
'            varWhere = ""
'        Else
        'The WHERE clause does NOT need the word "WHERE"

            ' strip off "WHERE " in the filter
            varWhere = Mid(varWhere, 7)
'        End If

    DoCmd.OpenReport "rpt_Vehicles", acPreview, , varWhere
    End Sub
```

To have it open either way:

```
Private Sub cmdPrint_Click()
Dim varWhere As Variant
    varWhere = BuildFilter

    ' Update the record source
    Me.RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM q_Vehicles " & varWhere

    ' Requery the form
    Me.Requery

    ' Check if there is a filter to return...
    If IsNull(varWhere) Then
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rpt_Vehicles", acPreview ' Open form directly if no filter is supplied

    Else
    'The WHERE clause does NOT need the word "WHERE"

        ' strip off "WHERE " in the filter
        varWhere = Mid(varWhere, 7)
        DoCmd.OpenReport "rpt_Vehicles", acPreview, , varWhere ' Open with criteria
    End If


End Sub
```